# Magnitude of maximal value

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Say I have an equation consisting of sines and cosines, e.g. 
$y=9\exp(2t)+\exp(-3t)\sin(5t)+4\cos(9t).$  What does it mean when a questions asks to find the magnitude of the maximal value of $y$?

Comment: This question seems to be incomplete. In the text where it occurred, there may have been some discussion of why that particular equation occurs, what the possible values of $t$ are, and so forth. You would need to provide that information in order for anyone to make sense of the question.

Comment: the function is y = y(t) and I got that equation using laplance tranforms.